# Subtitles in tableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am developing an iOS application that will act as a kind of email client.
One of the views in my story board is an inbox in which I would like to display for each email:

**The sender of the message, the title of the conversation, the begining of the message body and the date & time at which the message was sent.**

I have used a UITableViewController to display the list of emails and the UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle as the table's cell style (this allows me to set cell.textLabel.text and cell.detailTextLabel.text).

Is there a way to display more than 2 labels in such a table?

Many thanks.

Comment: You need to create a `UITableViewCell` subclass, and add the `UILabel's` you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `UITableViewCell` subclass, using File > New > File and select Objective-C class. Set the class to be `UITableViewCell`.

Now create a xib file, using File > New > File and under User Interface, select View, name it the same as your subclass you have just created.

In Interface Builder, delete the temporary View and drag in a UITableViewCell from the Views on the right. Click it, and under the identity inspector, change it's 'Custom Class' to be the `UITableViewCell` subclass you created.

Now create your labels, and their respective IBOutlets in the class you created. Then all you need to do is register your class with the UITableView:

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[YourSubClass class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

And in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, return your custom cell and set the labels.

A simple Google search finds the answer and detailed tutorial:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-crafting-custom-uitableview-cells--mobile-15702

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboards, use the prototype cells with the same explanation of Jeffs answer. It would be more easy.